# Python3 gspread error when opening sheet

Tags: python, json, python-3.4, gspread

I downloaded gspread with pip and pip3 for both python 3.4 and python 2.7. When running the code below with python (2.7.6) it runs without a problem, but when running it on python3 (3.4.3) it throws this error, please help, I dont know what to do. I tried upgrading request but didnt do any difference.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
        sheet = client.open('Test').sheet1
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 82, in open
feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 155, in get_spreadsheets_feed
r = self.session.get(url)
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
      File "/home/marbj634/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 65, in request
response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

My code is only:

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import pprint

    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

    sheet = client.open('Test').sheet1

    values = sheet.get_all_values()

    pp.pprint(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

oh I tried upgrading request but needed to upgrade requests. simple mistake, works not, so solved!